# Why should I use JSF instead of using easy ZK framework

Tags: java, jsf, zk

I have found the ZK Java Web framework very easy because of its built in support for Ajax, so why should I use JSF? I have found JSF's Ajax i.e. A4J not as good as ZK's Ajax.

Comment: For one, I try to minimize dependencies. Why use an external framework when JSF is standard in the JEE framework?

Comment: JSF 2 has built-in AJAX support too. You dont need a4j anymore.

Comment: But ZK's Ajax is very is to use than JSF

Comment: If you want to compare features, have you heard of [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) and how does it compare to ZK Framework? PrimeFaces is built on JSF.

Comment: i have used RichFaces and Tomahawk in JSF, they provides extra features in view layer like calender, t:savestate and so on... but these all features can be used directly in ZK, we don't need extra jar files... m i wrong ?

Comment: @Kerem Baydogan no need to add dependencies like library file like in JSF in ZK for view layer...

Comment: I just done a stress test on both ZK and PrimeFaces:

Comment: several points:


For ZK side:



1. Do you need good client side speed with a huge amount of dom element?
If so, I suggest ZK. When I record the test script of a case that a grid (data table) contains 10 columns * 2000 rows, browser complains slow script while ROD in PrimeFaces but works well in ZK.



2. Do you need very fast response of ajax request?
If so, I suggest ZK, the average response time is 5 times faster than PrimeFaces
(I think this is not important while considering the network latency, this point can just ignored I think)



next comment for JSF side

Comment: For JSF side:

1. Do you want shrink the memory usage?

If so, I suggest JSF, It uses 2/3 memory (compared with ZK) since it is more stateless (since JSF actually still a page based framework, not strongly ajax)

2. Do you want make more user on fewer machine?

If so, I suggest JSF, since memory usage is smaller, JSF can make 2 times (or more) larger amount of user on a machine.

Comment: It seems weird that JSF use 2/3 memory but can loading over 2 times more, I guess the cause is JSF is more stateless so most of memory can be GCed as needed.

Comment: It really comes down to whether you just hate web UI devs or really, really hate web UI devs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You decide

1. JSF is a Java EE standard
2. ZK is much faster than JSF
3. ZK has "ZK JSF components" but compatible only with JSF 1.2
4. ZK has easy to use built in Ajax support while JSF 2.0 also supports Ajax well
5. ZK is Easier to learn
6. Finally there are 12000 JSF related questions in Stackoverflow while ZK has 250

Comment: Yes you r correct. In real world JSF is highly demanded equals to Spring but ZK's demand is increasing very fast...

Comment: For 5) What is easier to learn?

Comment: @Prabhat Subedi, `In real world JSF is highly demanded equals to Spring`. In what sense?

Comment: @Buhake Sindi, I have found that in our country, when java developer is required by company they prefer JSF or Spring rather than ZK...

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is actually: **It depends**. There is no silver bullet for this issue.

JSF 2 comes with built-in AJAX support. Alternatively, if you want rich GUI with AJAX support, PrimeFaces, ICEFaces and others have rich capabilities built-in.

In essence, your view layer will mostly depend on the GUI, but in the Service Layer, one don't need to reference to PrimeFaces code, only Faces API.

It's all in a matter of taste: If you find ZK Framework easier to use than JSF, by all means, use it. At the end of the day, the client **never cares** about what Framework or architecture you've used to make your system, as long as the system does what it's supposed to do.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you like zk, use it. There is, afaik, no reason agaist zk.
I mean, its open source and there are no known big issues.
So the trade off is the features of zk vs external depandency,
as Buhake Sindi mentioned, and this you need to know your self.

Comment: I didn't speak about features. I spoke about external dependencies vs. built-in framework.

Comment: what external dependencies are u talking about ?

Comment: ZK Framework is an external library, while JSF is standard in JEE framework. I don't need to download JSF API to start using it in my development.

Comment: then what is jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar ?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi ok, i got your poit and edit my awnser. But I think this is about personal/project goals and there is no silver bullet.